# Does PostgreSQL have a pseudo-column like "LEVEL" in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, connect-by, hierarchical-query, recursive-cte

Does PostgreSQL have a pseudo-column like "LEVEL" in Oracle?
If not, then how can we create a column similar to "LEVEL"?

Answer (score 21):

Postgres does not have [hierarchical queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm). No `CONNECT BY`, therefore also no `LEVEL`.

The additional module tablefunc provides the function [`connectby()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#TABLEFUNC-CONNECTBY-PARAMETERS) doing almost the same. See
[mthorley answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44576772/939860) for details.

Or you can use a standard [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) with a `level` column that's incremented with every recursion.
This query in Oracle:

```sql
SELECT employee_id, last_name, manager_id, LEVEL
FROM   employees
CONNECT BY PRIOR employee_id = manager_id;
```

.. can be translated to this recursive CTE in Postgres:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT employee_id, last_name, manager_id, 1 AS level
   FROM   employees

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.manager_id, c.level + 1
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN   employees e ON e.manager_id = c.employee_id
   )
SELECT *
FROM   cte;
```

Comment: Yup. `CONNECT BY` is cleaner and simpler for the things it can express, but much less flexible than `WITH RECURSIVE`.

Comment: I don't get where you would specify the starting condition, like for level 1 `manager_id` should be null; but when I add that to the first select it does not work

Comment: @Superdooperhero: You are thinking top-down. My query is bottom-up, `manager_id IS NULL` ends the recursion (iteration really). It's the stopping condition in your manner of speaking.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter How do I change the query to go top-down?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Postgres has support for "LEVEL" like Oracle.

But, as the other answers point out, you must have the **tablefunc** extension loaded.

If you have admin access to your Postgres database you can load it with this:

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;`

For additional info check the docs

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Here's a real life example of *connectby* from one of our apps. We are using it to find all the people who report up to a manager through their reporting tree.

```
SELECT system_user.system_user_id
    , system_user.first_name
    , system_user.last_name
    , team.mgr_id as managers_system_user_id
    , team.level
    , team.hierarchy
    FROM connectby('system_user_manager_rltnp'
                   , 'system_user_id'
                   , 'system_users_managers_id'
                   , 2963049 -- the users system_user_id
                   , 5       -- the max levels of depth
                   , '~')    -- the hierarchy delimiter
    AS team(rpt_id numeric, mgr_id numeric, level int, hierarchy text),
    system_user
    WHERE team.rpt_id = system_user.system_user_id
```

And it returns results like this. Here you can see the level, and also the whole hierarchy as a string.

```
"system_user_id","first_name","last_name","managers_system_user_id","level","hierarchy"
"2963049","Debbie","Buswell","",0,"2963049"
"2963045","Linda","Simply","2963049",1,"2963049~2963045"
"2963047","Cindy","Brouillard","2963049",1,"2963049~2963047"
"2963048","Sharon","Burns","2963049",1,"2963049~2963048"
"2963050","Marie-Eve","Casper","2963049",1,"2963049~2963050"
"2963051","Tammy","Cody","2963049",1,"2963049~2963051"
```

Answer (score 3):

The functionality using a **Connect By**, **Starts With**, and a **level** indicator that you are familiar with is available if you enable the **tablefunc** extension in postgres.  The syntax is slightly different, but if you understand **connect by** from oracle you will pick this up in about 90 seconds.  It is great and saved my bacon when I transformed an oracle system into a postgres system.

I gave all the detail to a similar question.
[Stackoverflow Connect By answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37846191/5410)