# ERROR: syntax error at or near "BY"¶ Position: 321

Tags: postgresql

How to convert below Oracle query to Postgres? Below is the error

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "BY"¶  Position: 321

Query

```
SELECT listagg(app_rule_cd,',') within GROUP (
ORDER BY abc_cd) AS ERR_LST,
  '1'                 AS JOIN1
FROM ABC_RULE
WHERE abc_cd IN
  ( WITH CTE AS
  (SELECT VAL FROM config_server WHERE NAME = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
  )
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR( VAL, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))
FROM CTE
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(VAL, '[^,]+')) + 1  // BY is position 321
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not explain what this query does, but the convoluted `connect by level` and `regexp_replace()` is a typically pattern to split a comma separated string into elements in Oracle.

That can be done way easier in Postgres:

```
SELECT string_agg(app_rule_cd,',' ORDER BY abc_cd) AS ERR_LST,
       '1'                                         AS JOIN1
FROM ABC_Rule
WHERE abc_cd = ANY ( (SELECT string_to_array(val, ',')
                      FROM config_server WHERE NAME = 'XXXXXXXXXX') )
```

Note the duplicated parentheses around the sub-query are necessary. Another way is to use the IN operator:

```
SELECT string_agg(app_rule_cd,',' ORDER BY abc_cd) AS ERR_LST,
       '1'                 AS JOIN1
FROM ABC_Rule
WHERE abc_cd IN (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(val, ','))
                 FROM config_server 
                 WHERE NAME = 'XXXXXXXXXX')
```

Comment: How to convert below Oracle Query to Postgres ?

`
select string_agg(A_Cd,',') within group (order by B_Cd) AS ERR_LST,'1' AS JOIN1 from TableA 
where B_Cd in (
WITH CTE AS (select VAL from config where NAME = 'XX')
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR( VAL, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))  FROM CTE 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(VAL, '[^,]+')) + 1);`

Comment: That's the same query as in your question and I have already answered that. If this does not solve your problem, then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62782512/edit) your question and add sample data and the expected result based on that data.

Comment: Yes, but your query seems to be not working. Could you please check once ?

Comment: Sorry, without some sample data and expected result any answer is only guess-work.